# Deleting all excel files in a folder through VB

Tags: vbscript

I am new to vb and would like your assistance in deleting all excel files from a specific folder.

Below if my code which is not working as I wanted:

```
Dim fs 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fs.FileExists("C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Daily_Reports\*.xlsx") Then
     fs.Deletefile "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Daily_Reports\*.xlsx", true
Else
     MsgBox "No"
End If
```

Comment: This is VBA (or VB6)  not VB.NET . They are two completely different things

Comment: Please use tags that actually apply to your question instead of randomly grabbing those that look familiar. If you don't know the language you're coding in, you probably shouldn't be writing code to do destructive things like delete files.

Comment: Thanks @Steve its vb6!

Comment: @Ken I'll make sure next time and I am new to vb6 not to programming! Thanks any way!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `fs.FileExists` will only check to see if a single file exists, so you can't use wildcards.

You can use the VBA / VB6 native function `Dir` to achieve the same thing, and the native function `Kill` instead of `DeleteFile`.  (`DeleteFile` **will** cope with wildcards, but `Kill` avoids needing the Scripting object.)

```
If Dir("C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Daily_Reports\*.xlsx") <> "" Then
    Kill "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Daily_Reports\*.xlsx"
Else
    MsgBox "No"
End If
```

If you are using VBScript, you can just use

```
Dim fs 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each File In fs.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Daily_Reports").Files
    If fs.GetExtensionName(File) = "xlsx" Then
        fs.DeleteFile File
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance... I have been able to this in VBA but need assistance to do the same in vb and this is the challenge I would like to see if there is any excel file in the folder and then delete all of those.

Comment: From memory (it's been a while since I used it), VB6 has the `Kill` and `Dir` functions.

Comment: Thanks but it gives me follwoing error, Error: "Type mismatch: 'Dir'" Code: 800A000D Soure: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: Are you using VB6 or VBScript?

Comment: @IrvinSyed - I have updated the answer to show what to use if you are using VBScript instead of VB6

Comment: Many thanks @YowE3K for your assistance I have managed to delete the files the way I wanted! Thanks everyone! Much appreciated!

Comment: @IrvinSyed - please satisfy my (and probably other's) curiosity - is it VB6 or VBScript that you are trying to use?

Comment: this one was specifically related to VBScript. I am actually filing in for someone and editing some already developed routines in VBA, VB6 and VBScript. So I am trying to get adjusted with all of them at the same time. P.S apologies if I have not made technical sense before!